# html file displaying question marks in R instead of Hebrew characters

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, hebrew

R seems to support Hebrew input and output for everything and file type except my htm files.

I tried setting the locale and encoding in R and saving the htm file with UTF-8 encoding. The problem doesn't seem to be with R but with the htm file itself because it displays the same in the text editor; however, it displays correctly in the preview browser window.

## Here dome code I've tried in R already.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Hebrew")
locale = locale(date_names = "he", encoding = "UTF-8"))
locale("he")
```

Here's what the files look like when I print them in the R console...

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//HE\">\n<HTML DIR=\"RTL\" LANG=\"HE\">\n<HEAD>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset==Windows-1255\">\n<!--Copyright 2003 Mechon Mamre, 12 Hayyim Vital, Jerusalem-->\n<LINK REL=\"stylesheet\" HREF=\"x.css\" TYPE=\"text/css\">\n<TITLE>??\"? ????? ?????? - ??????"
```

I've fixed this problem before... I think I just saved the files as UTF-8, but I recently moved from Windows 10 to the Ubuntu 18 and that's just not working anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you requested R to read UTF-8 and the file is cp-1255.

You should re-save the file as UTF-8 (and update the header accordingly).

Comment: as it currentlys atnds, this looks more like a comment than a real answer; maybe improve?